# Instant stop when character is on the ground and movement keys are not pressed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to look for a solution online but I couldn't find anything that can help. I want to be able to move but I want my character to stop it's velocity if no key is being pressed AND if it is not in the ground.

I tried combining both if statements with '&&' but it doesn't work like how I wanted.

```cs
public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D rb;

    public float moveSpeed = 2000f;
    public float jumpSpeed = 20f;
    private bool grounded;

    private void FixedUpdate ( )
    {
        if ( Input.GetKey ( "d" ) )
        {
            rb.AddForce ( new Vector2 ( moveSpeed, 0f ) * Time.deltaTime );
            Debug.Log ( "d" );
        }

        if ( Input.GetKey ( "a" ) )
        {
            rb.AddForce ( new Vector2 ( -moveSpeed, 0f ) * Time.deltaTime );
            Debug.Log ( "a" );
        }

        if ( Input.GetKey ( "w" ) && grounded )
        {
            //rb.AddForce(new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpSpeed));
            Jump ( );
            Debug.Log ( "w" );
        }
    }

    private void Jump ( )
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2 ( rb.velocity.x, jumpSpeed );
        grounded = false;
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D ( Collision2D collision )
    {
        if ( collision.gameObject.tag == "ground" )
            grounded = true;
        if ( Input.GetKey ( "d" ) == false && Input.GetKey ( "a" ) == false && collision.gameObject.tag == "ground" )
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2 ( 0, rb.velocity.y );
            Debug.Log ( "stopped" );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if it is **not** on the ground then

1. You would check for `!grounded` instead of `collision.gameObject.tag == "ground"`
2. It is no use to check this in `OnCollisionEnter2D` since it will not collide when it is not on the ground

So probably rather e.g. (I would also rather change the velocity instead of using `AddForce` in this case)

```
private void FixedUpdate ( )
{
    var velocity = rb.velocity;
    var moveKeyPressed = false;

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    {
        moveKeyressed = true;
        velocity.x += moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime; 
        // or actually you could set it depending on your desired UX 
        //velocity.x = moveSpeed;
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        moveKeyressed = true;
        velocity.x -= moveSpeed * time.deltaTime;
    }

    if (grounded && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        velocity.y = jumpSpeed;
        grounded = false;
    }

    if (!moveKeyPessed && !grounded)
    {
        velocity.x = 0;
    }

    rb.velocity = velocity;
}

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("ground")) grounded = true;
}
```